# my compiler gives me this error yet what is saying is there?

Tags: java

```
public void String printRentalList(){
    for(int v = 0; v < numOfRoomsHR; v++){
        System.out.println(theRooms[v].toString);
    }
}
public void addReservation(Room a){
    if (numOfRoomsHR < theRooms.legnth){
        theRooms[numOfRoomsHR] = a;
        numofRoomsHR++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Can not add anymore rooms to the hotel");
    }
}
public void String findReservation(int l){
    boolean flag = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfRoomsHR && !flag; i++){
        if(theRooms[i] == l){
            flag = true;
            System.out.println("Reservation found for room number:" + l + "\n" + theRooms[i].toString);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Reservation not found for room number:" + l);
        }
    }
}
```

I was working through my project and compile checking to see if I did anything wrong through out the project I got this error:

> error: '(' expected

For the line `printRentalList()` and the `PrintList()` yet the `(` is there. any suggestions ?

Comment: `void String` -- Choose one.  Also, change `legnth` to `length`.

Comment: Use a proper IDE. It will tell you more precisely where you are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably the .toString on this line:

```
System.out.println("Reservation found for room number:" + l + "\n" + theRooms[i].toString);
```

Java would expect the ( after toString, as toString() is a method. I also noticed, as rgettman said: you have multiple return types with void and String. You do need to pick one and it seems, at least for the second function it should be void since you do not appear to be returning anything.